# VBA is not saved when MS Access is closed

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a database set up on MS Access 2007.
On the BeforeUpdate selection on the Form properties, I have placed the below macro:

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    If MsgBox("Changes have been made to this record." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Do you want to save these changes?", vbYesNo, "Save?") = vbYes Then
            DoCmd.Save
        Else
            DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdUndo
    End If
End Sub
```

When the VBA is saved, Forms run as expected.
The issue is: When Access is closed and reopened the form does not ask whether it needs to be saved (ie the VBA code is not executed). Please assist

How can I make the VBA code constant?

Answer (score 1):

Form BeforeUpdate event is ***not triggered*** **unless** the **record** or **any control's data** is changed. In other words, if you open and close the form without making any changes (either manually or programmatically) the event will never be triggered. This might explain why this is not asking you the option.

If you are using the Form's **Record Selector**, then you can easily identify if the event would be triggered or not. IF the record selector goes form being a Triangle to a Pencil, the even will be triggered, if not it will not be because no changes are made.

Hope that helps.